# How to integrate sonarqube build breaker plugin with gitlab CI?

Tags: sonarqube

I want to know how to setup a GitLab CI/CD build where the build breaks if the quality gate is breached.

I am on sonarqube version 6.7.3 . I already have gitlab plugin installed in sonarqube.